# How to tunnel browser-side mqtt through the server?

Tags: node.js, mqtt, paho

Browser uses this to connect to a mosquitto (websockets mode):

```
new Paho.MQTT.Client('localhost', 9001, '');
```

As I understand, it's a direct connection from the browser to the broker. It won't work in the normal setup when the browser is on a different machine.

In normal setup nodejs and the broker are on the same machine. How to route that via nodejs, so nodejs could forward the connections to the `localhost:9001`? And I don't want to write a lot of code for repacking messages and reimplementing different subscription API.

Comment: There are various proxies that support websocket proxying, like [`node-http-proxy`](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) or [`rocky`](https://github.com/h2non/rocky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost` is a special case hostname that refers to the machine some code is running on.

Assuming the broker you want to connect to is on the same machine that hosted the webpage you can use the `location` variable to get the information you need.

```
var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(location.hostname, 9001, '');
```

Assuming you are proxying the webapp then the websockets can be proxied as well on the same port which would end up with:

```
var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(location.hostname, parseInt(location.port), '');
```

To proxy the mqtt as well (using nginx):

```
location /mqtt {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
}
```

Comment: It's not supposed to be exposed to the internet. And I can't have that port open.

Comment: Then how is your app accessed? If you have nginx/apache proxying for the app, then it can proxy the Websockets to the broker as well and use the same port (80?)

Comment: that sounds like a right solution, but where will the TLS part emerge on the browser-side when I enable it on nginx?

Comment: That should probably be asked as a separate question

Comment: that's a way to get a comment like "it's an XY problem".

Comment: I've changed title from"How to tunnel mqtt through the nodejs?" to "How to tunnel browser-side mqtt through the server?" and added `parseInt(port)` + nginx to the answer. The https is not a problem - just a `useSSL: true` in `client.connect()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just open up another port and then setup an SSH Tunnel (i.e. SSH Tunnel the MQTT Data). The advantage of doing this is that it allows you to exposed or not expose this port to the internet with ease and it is secure (encrypted).

This tutorial explains how to do this. Obviously as the MQTT data is transmitted over SSH (through the SSH Tunnel) it is 100% encrypted and therefore secure. Also you could of course use RSA keys (making the SSH connection very secure indeed) and then write a simple BASH script to automation all of this process I guess. Tutorial Link:
[SSH Tunnel MQTT](http://www.miniaturelinux.com/Dynamic-SSH-Tunnel-Example.php#SSH-Tunnel-MQTT-Data-Example)

Comment: But there is no way to get a web browser to tunnel the websockets connection over the SSH link so this is unlikely to be helpful

Comment: @ hardillb: Yes you can. I do it via a SOCKS5 proxy over SSH (on a different port to the MQTT Data SSH port). The trick is to forward all ports of course.

Comment: That only works for users that can ssh to the server, this doesn't scale to a normal web page deployment where you want any random web browser to work.